# Force CodeBlocks To Build Unchanged (Up-to-date) codes

Tags: codeblocks

I would like to know how to make codeblock, when I press build button, always compile the hole code, even if the code has not changed. Right now, when I try to build, it shows the following message:

```
Target is up to date.
Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date).
```

I would like to force it to build again, even if the resulting `.exe` is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Codeblocks 12.11, there is a a "Rebuild" (Ctrl-F11) option under the Build menu or when right-clicking on a project.  This forces recompilation and averts the "up to date" message.

Comment: Is there a way to have a button or shortcut to "Rebuild and run"? Because I have to click "Rebuild" and then click "Run" every time. This is very annoying...

Comment: @user2562505: Sorry, I took a look but didn't see an easy way to do it, though I'm sure it's possible somehow.    Maybe ask a new question, or edit this one, as you see fit.